# php requests to mysql not working - join with multiple table - nothing shown

Tags: php, mysql

I have a difficulty with php and MySQL. I have 3 tables in MySQL:

- artist (id, artist_name)
- album (id, album_name, artist_id)
- track (id, artist_id, album_id, title, link, qr_code)

I am trying to create a php request to mysql in order to show all the albums and tracks linked to an artist already selected by the user.

The user selects the artist from a drop-list and php gets the artist_id.

I am trying the following code, but nothing is shown.

```php
<?php 
$artist_id=$_POST['artist_id'];

$track_select=$connection->prepare('
    SELECT *,
        artist.id AS artist_id;
        artist.artist_name AS artist_name, 
        album.id AS album_id;
        album.album_name AS album_name 
        track.artist_id AS track_artist_id, 
        track.album_id AS track_album_id
    FROM track 
    LEFT JOIN album ON album_id = track_album_id 
    LEFT JOIN artist ON artist_id = track_artist_id 
    WHERE (track_artist_id=:artist_id)');
$track_select->bindParam(':artist_id', $artist_id);
$track_select->execute();

while($donnees=$track_select->fetch())
{ 
    echo $donnees['artist_name'].' '.$donnees['album_name'].' '.$donnees['title'].'<br />';
}
$track_select->closeCursor();
?>
```

I would need your help to see where I made the mistake.

thank you.

Comment: please edit your query. you can put many time semicolon.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and/or check your error logs. Does the query return rows when run directly against your database?

Comment: what are those semi colon in the select clause instead of commas? typo?
have you tried your query in some phpmyadmin in order to see if it return any result? shouldn't the from clause start with artist and then proceed with album and track joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use column name alis  in where or in ON join codnition

```
  $track_select=$connection->prepare('
      SELECT *,
          artist.id AS artist_id;
          artist.artist_name AS artist_name, 
          album.id AS album_id;
          album.album_name AS album_name 
          track.artist_id AS track_artist_id, 
          track.album_id AS track_album_id
      FROM track 
      LEFT JOIN album ON album.id = track.album_id 
      LEFT JOIN artist ON artist.id = track.artist_id 
      WHERE (tarck.artist_id=:artist_id)');
  $track_select->bindParam(':artist_id', $artist_id);
  $track_select->execute();
```

Comment: Hello, indeed, when I did remove the alias in Where and in On join, the problem is solved. thank you.